# MongoDB crashes on windows randomly with WiredTiger exception

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I have MongoDB 3.2 installed on Windows Server 2008 R2

randomly MongoDB service crashed with the following log. How can I address this issue?

Here is the log

> 2016-12-13T10:08:33.497-0800 E STORAGE  [thread2] WiredTiger (-28968)
>   [1481652513:490570][2036:2006004608], file:WiredTiger.wt,
>   WT_SESSION.checkpoint: D:\MongoDB\data\db\WiredTiger.turtle.set to
>   D:\MongoDB\data\db\WiredTiger.turtle: file-rename: rename: The process
>   cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
>
> 2016-12-13T10:08:33.497-0800 E STORAGE  [thread2] WiredTiger (-28968)
>   [1481652513:497570][2036:2006004608], checkpoint-server: checkpoint
>   server error: The process cannot access the file because it is being
>   used by another process.
>
> 2016-12-13T10:08:33.498-0800 E STORAGE  [thread2] WiredTiger (-31804)
>   [1481652513:498571][2036:2006004608], checkpoint-server: the process
>   must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
>   2016-12-13T10:08:33.498-0800 I -        [thread2] Fatal Assertion
>   28558 2016-12-13T10:08:33.498-0800 I -        [thread2]
>
> ***aborting after fassert() failure
>
> 2016-12-13T10:08:33.562-0800 I -        [WTJournalFlusher] Fatal
>   Assertion 28559 2016-12-13T10:08:33.562-0800 I -
>   [WTJournalFlusher]
>
> ***aborting after fassert() failure

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19881 this might be helpful.

Comment: I'm getting this as well. Where can I submit a bug ticket?

Comment: Here is where it was fixed earlier this year. But I'm still reproducing it. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29439

Answer (score 1):

I do Tech Support for a Security Orchestration and Automation platform that uses MongoDB as a primary data store. I've seen this error at two different customer sites. The first time that I saw this error was August 2017, and I worked with MongoDB Support to determine that the most likely cause is a virus scanner opens D:\MongoDB\data\db\WiredTiger.turtle.set and prevents mongod.exe (one of its threads or subordinate processes) from renaming it. That customer took pains to ensure that no virus scanner would inspect files in the MongoDB data folder, and the symptom has not reappeared for that customer.

I have a second customer who has seen this symptom twice this week, and I'm working with them to prevent virus scanners from accessing --dbpath...